# Search Load Balancing by tag

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cli

I have a classic load balancer on AWS with a key tag "Owner" and value "engineer". Is there any way to retrieve the name of this load balancer by this tag using aws cli?

Answer (score 3):

AWS cli does not have native ways to do it.
You can use [jq](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/) with AWS cli

```bash
for i in $(aws elbv2 describe-load-balancers | jq -r '.LoadBalancers[].LoadBalancerArn'); do aws elbv2 describe-tags --resource-arns "$i" | jq -ce '.TagDescriptions[].Tags[] | select( .Key == "Owner" and .Value == "engineer")' && echo "$i" ;done
```

Comment: You don't actually need jq. You can use the CLI's native "--query" syntax to filter and format the output as needed, eg
--query "LoadBalancers[].LoadBalancerArn" --output text

Answer (score 0):

To get Load Balancer by multiple tags

```bash
aws elbv2 describe-load-balancers | jq -r '.LoadBalancers[].LoadBalancerArn' | xargs -I {} aws elbv2 describe-tags --resource-arns {} --query "TagDescriptions[?Tags[?Key=='env' &&Value=='dev'] && Tags[?Key=='created_by' &&Value=='xyz']].ResourceArn" --output text
```

Currently, AWS doesn't have any native way to filter by tags, for now recursively get the arn of all load balancers then get all tags of all load balancers and then filter with your tags. Too much work here for a simple operation. AWS should bring improvements here.